# Azure App Service to Azure SQL very high latency

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-app-service-plans

I have a Asp.Net Core app talking to an Azure SQL database which is in the SouthCentral US. When I run the app locally (from Wisconsin) and point to the Azure SQL in SouthCentral US, the app responds in approximately 2 seconds (SQL query is a little complex with table valued parameter, cross apply and a CTEs). So I'm ok with 2 second response time.

When I deploy this app to an Azure App Service in SouthCentral US (Same as DB), it takes minimum of 15 seconds to respond.

Looking at the application insights, the app says the SQL dependency took 600ms. When I added log statements before and after the SQL call, I see the logs are being emitted at least 14 seconds apart from each other.

So far I've tried the obvious things. Moving app and DB to same region. Changing the App Service Plan (sizes tried: S1, S2, P2V2, B3). Scaled the database from standard 10 - 100 DTUs. Even tried deleting the resource group and re-deploying every time I changed the app service plan size, instead of using the 'Scale Up' feature. Nothing seems to be helping.

Any other thoughts on troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: check if this is the only query/ SP that is slow or other queries are too.. in general the calls would go via the internet even though both resources are on azure. It will add some latency. to avoid it you can enable vnet service endpoints for sql azure and make call from an app from within a vnet. for app services to be bound to vnet u need ASE which is expensive though.

Comment: Please look at the query store to see how long the query takes in the database engine.  That might help you isolate where to look

Comment: Aravind, its happening with all queries not just one. All queries are significantly longer from App Service. @ConorCunninghamMSFT , Looking at the profiler the query in DB Engine is taking ~1.5 seconds (Duration: 1496644 in profiler).  I'm switching from traditional windows app service to containers on linux, hoping to see some difference. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I'm convinced its an issue with App Service Plan (Windows). I moved my app to an App Service Plan : Linux (Containers) and published my app as container via ACR. Now it runs significantly faster on a B1 size than previous Win:P2V2 plan, and a smidge faster than my local machine.  Now app is responding in ~1.8 seconds on ASP-Linux-Container:B1, ~2 seconds locally, and ~15 seconds ASP-Windows:P2V2.